# Show days in future without series

Tags: highcharts

I have a general highcharts question, because I havent found something about that so far.
Is it possible to show empty space in the future?.
I have a plotLine, which marks today like:

```
xAxis : {
            plotLines:[{
                value: today,
                color: '#ff0000',
                dashStyle: 'solid',
                width: 2,
                zIndex: 5,
                label : {
                    text : 'Today, '+currentDate.getDate()+"."+(currentDate.getMonth()+1)+"."+currentDate.getFullYear(),
                    style: {
                        color: '#ff0000'
                    },
                    x: -15
                }
            }],
              type: 'datetime'
        },
```

And now i just want to display e.g. 60 days in future after today without series.

Answer (score 0):

You can set min/max values on xAxis or add null values in serie.

Comment: well min/max values as well as minPadding only works on yAxis. Is there no other way?